# Python записывает только один элемент в excel файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Пожалуйста помогите с данным вопросом, я записываю спаршенные данные в словарь, а потом в csv файл, но в файл записывается только строка с последним элементом.

```py
for mark_etc in marks_etc:
    if count == 0:
        art = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.properties-list__right')[0]
        time.sleep(2)

        mark = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[2]
        time.sleep(2)

        model = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[3]
        time.sleep(2)

        generation = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[4]
        time.sleep(2)

        main_info_2.append({
            'art': art.text,
            'mark': mark.text,
            'model': model.text,
            'generation': None,
            'generation2': None,
            'generation3': None
            }) 

        save_file_2(main_info_2, file_2)

    else:
        pass

    count += 1

    if count == 1:
        generation = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[4]
        time.sleep(2)

        mark = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[2]
        time.sleep(2)

        model = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[3]
        time.sleep(2)

        main_info_2.clear()

        main_info_2.append({
            'art': art.text,
            'mark': mark.text,
            'model': model.text,
            'generation': generation.text,
            'generation2': None,
            'generation3': None
            })

        save_file_2(main_info_2, file_2)

    else:
        pass

    if count == 2:
        generation2 = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[4]
        time.sleep(2)

        mark = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[2]
        time.sleep(2)

        model = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[3]
        time.sleep(2)

        main_info_2.clear()

        main_info_2.append({
            'art': art.text,
            'mark': mark.text,
            'model': model.text,
            'generation': generation.text,
            'generation2': generation2.text,
            'generation3': None
            })

        save_file_2(main_info_2, file_2)
        
    else:
        pass

    if count == 3:
        generation3 = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[4]
        time.sleep(2)

        mark = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[2]
        time.sleep(2)

        model = mark_etc.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[3]
        time.sleep(2)

        main_info_2.clear()

        main_info_2.append({
            'art': art.text,
            'mark': mark.text,
            'model': model.text,
            'generation': generation.text,
            'generation2': generation2.text,
            'generation3': generation3.text
            })

        save_file_2(main_info_2, file_2)

    else:
        pass
```

Также есть функция записи в файл

```py
def save_file_2(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Артикул', 'Марка' , 'Модель' , 'Поколение_1', 'Поколение_2', 'Поколение_3'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['art'], item['mark'] , item['model'] , item['generation'], item['generation2'], item['generation3']])
```

Comment: записываются все элементы. Но каждый последующий переписывает предыдущий, в итоге остается только последний.

Comment: А сколько элементов в `items` передается в `save_file_2`?

Comment: @gil9red в items передаётся список main_info_2, а в нём все элементы, как я понял

Comment: @Эникейщик, это я понял, но как это решить, думаю уже день, и никак не могу допереть, проблема в том, что в другом варианте, записываются 3 одинаковых item-а, и всего два generation-а для них, короче одна строка записывается правильно, а две остальные нет, в этом варианте, я сохраняю файл в конце цикла

Answer (score 0):

Солгасно [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) `mode = "w"` означает, что файл открывается на запись, содержимое файла удаляется, если файла не существует, создается новый.

Для того чтобы дописать в существующий файл необходимо использовать `"a"`, открывает файл для добавления если он существует

```py
...
with open(path, 'a', newline='') as file:.... # здесь
```

Comment: Тогда у него каждый раз заголовок таблицы будет записываться :) Автору нужно сначала собрать все данные, после для всех собранных данных вызвать ту функцию

Comment: да, пофиксить надо весь метод. Написать функцию инициализации файла с заголовками (через него так же можно проверять сущесвует файл или нет), а только потом дописывать в него